# UISearchController request to webservice without stacking many requests

Tags: ios, swift, api, uisearchcontroller

I'm using the `UISearchController` to get objects to my `tableview`. My main problem is about stacking a lot of requests while the user types the text.

Every time the user type a character, the controller sends another request to my api and it does not make sense to me, because the first request will be for sure the longest one (if the user types "a", a lot of items is coming and the request will take a lot of time), and it will overwrite the short request.

1. User types: a (first request will take 10seconds to take everything which contains a)
2. User keep typing: bacate (a lot of request being faster then the first one)
3. The api returns all the requests for bacate (fruit abacate) and will show in screen.
4. The api NOW (because takes a lot of time) returns the request for the single a and overwrite with all fruits which contains a.

Sorry for the mess of my question, I'm really confused.

Thanks

Comment: When the search data is delivered, start a timer for a few seconds. When that timer expires, submit the search request to your API. If another character is delivered before he timer fires, restart the timer.

Comment: @Paulw11 what should I do if another character is delivered after the timer expires, but before the api response? Should I just let it shows the result awaint for the new result?

Comment: Start the timer again as normal.  If the timer expires again then submit another request.  There isn't much point in cancelling an existing request since it will probably have almost completed before the timer expires again anyway.  The trick is to set the timer short enough that your UI is responsive but not so short that your API gets spammed with lots of useless queries.  Generally people will type fairly quickly before pausing to review results and then maybe typing some more to further refine, so in practice multiple concurrent queries aren't a big problem

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paulw11 I'll give it a try! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can send the requests with delay and cancel the previous request.
Here my example:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText != "" {
        // to limit network activity, reload half a second after last key press.
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(MyController.search), object: nil)
        self.perform(#selector(MyController.search), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
    }
}

func search() {

    // Send request

}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try too! Do you know if its a recomended approach from Apple?

Comment: I don't know, It's the solution that the most developers use for this case

Answer (score 0):

You can add throttling to the search

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // to limit network activity, reload half a second after last key press.
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.sendRequest), object: nil)
    self.perform(#selector(self.reload), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
}
func sendRequest() {
    print("send request")
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Jasmeet! Is it the same approach @DiegoQ has sent before?

Comment: sorry didn't reloaded my screen before posting the answer. Yes it is same